# Getting the attendance average of each unit in MySQL

Tags: mysql, average

I'm trying to fix my problem on using AVG, I found some similar/relevant solutions and have attempted to apply it on my query however I still couldn't get the correct solution.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT unt_id, sum(enteredCode)  / count(DISTINCT unt_id) AS 'avg' FROM tbl_code GROUP BY unt_id
```

Where enteredCode has the value of 1 and unt_id could be Chemistry, Physics, etc.

I think I'm missing something as it only shows the sum not the average.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use the AVG function:

```
Select unt_id, avg(enteredCode) from tbl_code group by unt_id
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this many times and totally works. I think, after reading @Patrick Marchand's explanation, I will now going to resolve about the issue enteredCode's value.

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking of GROUP BY as taking a big pile of rows and putting them into smaller piles, where each smaller pile is identified with a unique value among all groups.

In your query:

```
SELECT unt_id
     , sum(enteredCode)  / count(DISTINCT unt_id) AS 'avg' 
  FROM tbl_code 
 GROUP BY unt_id
```

you have asked to have all the rows grouped by unt_id and if unt_id has 6 distinct values like 1, 3, 9, 12, 18, 24 (across however many rows there are in the table), you'll have 6 groups where the first group consists of all rows where unt_id = 1, the second group where all rows have unt_id = 2, and so on.

Now what? Group functions like SUM(), COUNT(), AVG(), MAX(), MIN() will look at the individual groups of rows and give you one result per group.

Going back to your query, asking for COUNT(DISTINCT unt_id) for, say, the group where unt_id = 3, you're just going to get 1; the database put all rows where unt_id = 3 in that one group so there's only one distinct unt_id value. Same goes for groups 1, 9, 12, 18, and 24; they only have one distinct unt_id in their groups as well. (As an aside, note that using this grouping, MAX(unt_id) = MIN(unt_id) = unt_id for each group.)

If you just consider:

```
SELECT unt_id
     , count(DISTINCT unt_id) as dist_count 
  FROM tbl_code 
 GROUP BY unt_id
```

you'll get one row returned for each unique unt_id value in your data, and the dist_count will be 1 for each of them. Using this count in your own average calculation (SUM(enteredCode) / COUNT(DISTINCT unt_id)) you're basically just doing SUM(enteredCode) / 1 so you're only seeing the sum.

When you said "enteredCode has the value of 1" it sounds like 1 is the only value and if that was the case, the average isn't going to be all that exciting - it'll just be 1, too. Assuming enteredCode has other values, as @bitfiddler said, you can just used the AVG function and call it done, assuming that you're looking to find the average enteredCode for all of the rows in each unt_id group. (If you wanted to use the explicit SUM / COUNT calculation for the average, just remember that AVG() = SUM() / COUNT() and rows where  is null will not be considered.)

Hopefully this provides some insight as to why you're not getting the result you were intending.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I've tried @bitfiddler's answer. I'm getting "1" as the results. Well, yes, I think you're correct, if enteredCode contains "1" for each row then I will always get 1 as the result. Any suggestion?

Comment: I think I've resolved it. Thanks a lot for helping guys.